# Grouping elements in css and displaying one below other

Tags: html, css

I need the id3 displayed below id2 instead of being displayed on the side?

How can I accomplish it in using CSS?

html

```
<div class="main" ></div>
<div id="id1">Im in div1</div>
<div id="id2">Im in div2</div>
<div id="id3">Im in div3</div>
<div></div>
```

css

```
#id1{
    background-color:green;
    width:30%;  
    height:200px;
    border:100px;   
    float:left;
}

#id2{
    background-color:red;
    width:20%;  
    height:100px;
    border:100px;   
    float:left;
}

#id3{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:10%;  
    height:300px;
    border:100px;   
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9xPP/

Comment: HTML has something built-in to do this: <UL> and <LI>. DIVs should not be used for groups and lists.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/w9xPP/2/

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do it is to not use floats. The only reason to use them is to make things horizontal to other things. If you want things to fit together like a puzzle, look at [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `clear: left;` on `#id3` like

```
#id3{
clear: left;
background-color:red;
width:20%;  
height:100px;
border:100px;   
float:left;
}
```

When you use float it tells subsequent elements to attempt to display next to them rather than below. Using `clear` clears the floats and gets rid of that behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/w9xPP/1/

Comment: I want id3 to be displayed right below id2..id1 & id2 looks perfect..I added clear:left to id2 and it moves id2 below id1..

Comment: id1 & id2 should be side by side...id3 should occupy the remaining space below id2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to do columns. @Diodeus is right about the ULs and LIs. You will probably want to refactor that code. However, if you are trying to have two columns of elements you could wrap your elements in a div and float them instead of the items they contain. Your child elements would then be placed within the floated columns. You might also want to check out a grid system like the [960 Grid](http://grids.heroku.com/) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).